# Scrambled tooltips in visual studio - maybe Resharper

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tooltip, resharper

I am using a black theme for VS, and some of the tooltips (and inputfields in popup windows) are totally scrambled.

Anybody know where I can look to help this? It's driving me nuts

Below:Me hovering mouse over breakpoint

[image: Me hovering mouse over breakpoint]

Comment: My bet is on a graphic card drivers bug. Such visual glitches can't usually be the consequence of a bug in application code. Try disabling gfx hardware acceleration on your machine to see if it help and/or upgrading the drivers to the newest version available.

Comment: You are correct! If I drag it to another monitor (which is powered by another graphics card), the effect disappears! Tx

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem (and my search bars were additionally being distorted within VS2013), and as Jods suggested I updated my graphics drivers and disabled all the advanced settings from the graphics options on the hardware driver page... This didn't quite fix my problem alone until I did the following:

I was able to fix the problem by disabling "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available" within Visual Studio itself.

In Visual Studio go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General ->` Uncheck "`Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance`," and then uncheck "`Use hardware graphics acceleration if available`"

This immediately fixed my problem.